# Jenkins time out on private Bower repository

Tags: jenkins, private-bower

We had a bower registry on git hub. The Jenkins job been configured and the build was successful. Recently, we set up a bower private repository. When I trigger the build on Jenkins, its referring to all the url of the private bower repository but getting "Timed Out" and thereby, results in build failure.

Will changing registry to https or https-proxy in .bowerrc make the build successful? What's the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a private repository, chances are it is internal to your network, therefore you should not use any proxy. (you could try to unset it in .bowerrc)

Im sure you already checked the documentation but just in case https://bower.io/docs/config/#placement--order